# Find symmetry point/center point in an irregular image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to find symmetry lines or points in my image[image]

My main aim is to find the center of this contour. But I can't use thresholding, so can't use OpenCV contours.
So my next guess it to find symmetric point in my image and hopefully that will correspond to the center of this contour. Any other idea to find center of this contour is also appreciated, something which doesn't involve thresholding as I can't give parameters to user.
I tried finding centroid using cv moments but that didn't give me good results.
I tried using hough circle detection, but it couldn't detect this as circle.

I am using python and OpenCV.

Comment: Why can't you use an automated thresholding?

Comment: @mozway I tired Otsu's method, but it just made it black in upper half and white in lower. Also, there are thousands of different images of different nature, so won't be too reliable if not monitored.

Comment: I get your point, but this might hold true for other detection methods, maybe you could provide other examples

Comment: Most of the images are classified. But I'll see if I can get something in open domain.

Comment: Your title says *"irregular shape"* but your example shows a pretty decent circle. Is it a poor description or non-representative image?

Comment: @Mark It is one of the best looking contours. Some are pretty irregular. But all are somewhat closer to ellipse I'll say.

Comment: @A.k. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70781786/edit) your question to add what you have tried so far in terms of code [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), plus if you provide a bad looking scenario(image) it will be more representative to your question.

Comment: is this an eye/iris/pupil? vagueness helps nobody.

Comment: Suggestion: use Otsu on the whole image, then Otsu again over the area above the first threshold.

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather vague, lacking adequate sample images and there is little feedback to comments, so it is a stab in the dark as whether you are having difficulty separating the objects, or finding their lines of symmetry, but I wanted to point out that **ImageMagick** does a pretty good job of separating the objects using the algorithm described [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/quantize.php).

Here it is from command line with dithering suppressed:

```
magick IuOWe.jpg +dither -colors 3 result.jpg
```

[image]

And here with initial blurring:

```
magick IuOWe.jpg -blur 0x5 +dither -colors 3 result.jpg
```

[image]

Of course you can use similar techniques with OpenCV, or scikit-image as you have tagged Python - it is just quicker to demonstrate my avenue of thought using **ImageMagick**.